# JUnit Testing One-To-Many HashSet

Tags: java, jpa, junit

I am trying to learn testing in Spring Boot. I was trying to test my models but then I faced with NullPointer. Let's see the code.

**Genre.java**

```
public class Genre {

@Column(nullable = false)
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "genre", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Movie> movieSet;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Set<Movie> getMovie() {
    return movieSet;
}

public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    if (movieSet.size() == 0) {
        movieSet = new HashSet<>();
    }
    movieSet.add(movie);
}}
```

**GenreTest.java**

```
public class GenreTest {

@Test
public void IdGetterSetter() {
    Genre genre = new Genre();
    genre.setId(1);
    assertThat(genre.getId()).isEqualTo(1);

}

@Test
public void MovieGetterSetter(){

    Genre genre = new Genre();
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    genre.setMovie(movie);
    assertThat(genre.getMovie()).isEqualTo(movie);

}}
```

genre.setMovie(movie) is getting NullPointer error. What should I need to do? By the way, I am testing my getter and setter functions in the same function. Do I need to seperate them or is it okay to use it like that? Give me some opinion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    if (movieSet.size() == 0) {
        movieSet = new HashSet<>();
    }
    movieSet.add(movie); 
}}
```

movieSet is unitialized.

You either want to:

```
private Set<Movie> movieSet = new HashSet<>();
```

Or:

```
public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
    if (movieSet == null) {
        movieSet = new HashSet<>();
    }
    movieSet.add(movie); 
}}
```

Comment: I did it like Set<Movie> movieSet = new HashSet<>();
        movieSet.add(movie);
        genre.setMovie(movie);
        assertThat(genre.getMovie()).isEqualTo(movieSet); Thanks for help!